# Customize accuracy graph with lines and shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wrote a simple code to construct a graph and it works fine. But,
I have no idea how I can modify it like below?
How to customize lines in matplotlib?

**Requirement:**

[image]

**My Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for different models and their corresponding accuracies
models = ['10', '60', '110', '160']
accuracies = [73.2, 75.6, 77.1, 78.3]
transmix_accuracies = [74.8, 76.4, 78.2, 79.1]

# Create a figure and axis object
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the accuracy of ViT-based models
ax.plot(models, accuracies, marker='o', label='ViT')
# Plot the accuracy of TransMix models
ax.plot(models, transmix_accuracies, marker='o', label='TransMix')

# Set the chart title and axis labels
#ax.set_title("Improvement of TransMix on ViT-based Models")
ax.set_xlabel("Number of Parameters")
ax.set_ylabel("ImageNet Top-1 Acc (%)")

# Add a legend
ax.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add some instructions like:

```
# Modify lines with linestyle parameter
ax.plot(models, accuracies, marker='o', ls='--', label='ViT')
ax.plot(models, transmix_accuracies, marker='^', ls='-', label='TransMix')

# Set limits
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ymin, ymax = ymin - 2, ymax + 2
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

# Add arrows
ax.annotate('', xy=(0, transmix_accuracies[0]), xytext=(0, accuracies[0]), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', ls='--'))
ax.annotate('', xy=(3, transmix_accuracies[3]), xytext=(3, accuracies[3]), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', ls='--'))

# Add text
ax.text(0.5, ymin+0.5, 'small', ha='center')
ax.text(1.5, ymin+0.5, 'base', ha='center')
ax.text(2.5, ymin+0.5, 'large', ha='center')

# Enable grid
ax.grid(ls='--')
```

Now you can customize your graph with [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) or [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)

Output

[image]